# How to use another fonts on windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, fonts, windows-phone-8, textblock, windows-phone-8-emulator

I used "Algerian" for one textblock control at design time.

But when i ran it on emulator of windows phone 8 textblock appears with the default font Segoe UI. how can i change the font to algerian so that textblock appears with algerian font on emulator as well as device

Comment: How are you applying the font?

Comment: @ChrisW. by applying font family property

Comment: did you get the solution? I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this [post](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/) for detailed steps.

example,

```
<TextBlock Text="12:02 AM" FontFamily="fonts/DigitalDream.ttf#Digital Dream" FontSize="60"/>
```